# repeat an operation with every item in a comma list using bison / yacc

Tags: grammar, bison, interpreter, yacc

This is a small part of a larger homework assignment dealing with an interpreter.

Basically, I have an operation that when something is done like:

```
integer A, B, C
```

I want to actually run thru my process of creating 3 variables.

Currently in the yacc file:

```
declare:
      INT VAR { $$ = createvar(INT_T, $2); }
    | FLT VAR { $$ = createvar(FLT_T, $2); }
    ;
```

Where `createvar()` is part of the intermediate code generation to create variables.  The problem is I want to allow `VAR` to be a comma separated list and I'm honestly lost at what to do.  I've tried creating a var_list in the yacc file, and I think I can find some obscure ways of doing it.  However, I want to reuse as much code as possible, and I think there's probably a recursive way of doing this.

```
var_list:
      VAR { $$ = $1; }
    | var_list ',' VAR { $$ = ????; }
    ;
```

Can anyone recommend some ways of calling `createvar()` for each value in the list?

Comment: Do you use the semantic value of the `declare` non-terminal anywhere? What do you expect the value to be if there is more than one VAR?

Comment: yes, the declare is used elsewhere, but I can make a specific one for multiple declarations to avoid a problem.  I'm not sure what yeoman by the value.  I want to call createvar() once for each VAR in a list of comma separated VARs.

Comment: Let me put the question differently. You have $$ = .... I presume you know what that does. T he question: is it necessary? Do you subsequently *use* thevalue you stored in $$?

Comment: I've been looking at the return value for a while trying to figure it out.  it looks like I can't simply return a 1 or 0 and be good.  that meaning, I can't call createvar() over and over and have only one return to $$.  That said, I need something like a stack where for each item in the list I can run $$ = createvar(), pop one off the list, and run the next.  Otherwise, the interpreter won't run correctly.

Comment: I still don't know why you need to *assign to* $$. Can you explain what you expect the semantic value of a `declare` production to be, since that is what assigning to `$$` creates? If you don't need the value, and you only need to ensure that `createvar` is called, then there is a simple solution.

Comment: Well, the declare returns a datatype, and then that runs thru an intermediate code generation function.  There are some checks that occur in this step for the creation of variables.  basically, the createvar() generates a datatype for that variable (type, value, etc), returns it, and the intermediate code gen stuff checks to make sure it isn't already defined, inserts it in a symbol table, checks the scope, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start at the beginning, which in the case of a bottom-up parser is the bottom.

`var_list` is going to be a list of some kind, and it's going to have an `append()` method of some kind. It needs to be created where it first appears, which is the production

```
var_list ::= VAR
```

So the action there is going to be something like

```
{
    $$ = new VariableList();
    $$->append(create_var($1));
}
```

Now that you've started the list, it is appended to by the other production

```
| var_list ',' VAR
```

So the action there is something like

```
{
    $1->append(create_var($3));
    $$ = $1;
}
```

Then you process the list here:

```
declaration ::= INT var_list
{
    // process elements of the var_list $2 and assign them the type INT
}
```

And similarly for the FLT case.

Comment: when I say its a list, I mean its a list like "A, B, C" of comma separated values.  Unless bison/yacc create an append method....

Comment: No, *you* create the `append()` method, or you use a standard list class.

Comment: right, I get what you were trying to say now.  But the problem is that's not what I meant, nor what I wrote.  var_list has no methods, isn't a class, so you can see my confusion.  It should just be a non-terminal.

Comment: `var_list` *is* a non-terminal, but you need to *represent* or *model* it via the `$$ = ` assignment as a class or struct. Otherwise the information in the productions is just lost.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to create a list of names in the `var_list` rule:

```
var_list:
      VAR { $$ = create_singleton_list($1); }
    | var_list ',' VAR { $$ = append_to_list($1, $3); }
```

and run over it in the `declare` rule:

```
declare:
      INT var_list { $$ = create_vars_from_list(INT_T, $2); }
    | FLT var_list { $$ = create_vars_from_list(FLT_T, $2); }
```

of course, you need to worry about memory management for your lists to make sure they're cleaned up properly.

An alternative trick, which is occasionally useful, is to use an inherited attribute, for which bison has only limited support -- you can put them explicitly on the parser stack with appropriately located embedded actions and then access them with `$0`:

```
declare:
      INT { $<type>$ = INT_T; } var_list
    | FLT { $<type>$ = FLT_T; } var_list

var_list:
      VAR { createvar($<type>0, $1); }
    | var_list ',' VAR { createvar($<type>0, $3); }
```

this is very tricky to get right, and requires explicit casts (dangerous) and lots of care.  Alternately, you can use [btyacc](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/btyacc), which supports this directly:

```
declare:
      INT var_list(INT_T)
    | FLT var_list(FLT_T)

var_list($type):
      VAR { createvar($type, $1); }
    | var_list($type) ',' VAR { createvar($type, $3); }
```

Comment: This looks promising.... I'm not sure about using the value of var_list as $2 in the create_vars_from_list().  I may have to use some global list datatype because I won't be able to pass this data by value.